# Alternatives for "For the sake of completeness"?

Tags: phrase-requests, mathematics, science

I'd like to include in a paper on mathematics the phrase:

> "for the sake of completeness, we first show..."

or words to that effect. However, the word "*completeness*" has a precise technical interpretation in mathematics and so I'd prefer not to use it. Any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: 'To make the treatment comprehensive, ...'

Comment: To be thorough,...

Comment: For the sake of thoroughness/comprehensiveness

Answer (score 6):

In a paper on mathematics, you might say

> "For the sake of rigor, we first show..."

The concept of mathematical rigor is discussed [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/170965/452606)

Comment: Hi Robert, the system has flagged your answer for closure as "low-quality because of its length and content." Note that an answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid closure - for example, adding a dictionary definition for "rigor", linked to the source. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Something along the line "To cover every aspect, we show..." would help you out. If you want to avoid the word "cover", as it has a mathematical meaning, use "To deal with every aspect, we show..." instead which is less elegant, but causes no complications with mathematical terms.